# How to make a React site responsive

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have been using semantic ui for the components and the site turns out very nice on desktop, 
but it fairly breaks on mobile. 
How can I transform it to be fully responsive

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to read [this CSS guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

You can create a fully responsive website via Flex-box.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a responsive add-on for semantic, https://react.semantic-ui.com/addons/responsive/

Take a look through the documentation in the link above.  You will still have to make the choice yourself of how to make the UI be responsive, but you have helpers from semantic to help with breakpoints.

Ideally you want to start with the grid being responsive: https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a same question before After I learn media queries with CSS. You can build your app with any view-port with this.

refer this, for the beginer https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp